# Wordpress Widgets - Increment Variable

Tags: wordpress, widget, increment

Using the regular `register_sidebar` function in wordpress, I have a large number of widgets as the main content on the homepage. These work in a basic grid system, moving from left to right - dropping down onto a new line for number 4 etc.

I've used Incrementation (ie: `$i++`) before to separate dynamically created divs into rows, creating a new line. Is it possible to do the same with widgets so they too can go into rows?

**register_sidebar Code:**

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Homepage Widgets',
        'id' => 'homepage_widgets',
        'description'   => __('Homepage Widgets'),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s ht-grid-col ht-grid-4">',
        'after_widget' => '</section>',
        'before_title' => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
        )
    );
```

Comment: Can you not just use CSS? In other words, set the width of each widget `<section>` to `33.33%`? If the width is set like that, the 4th should drop to a new row automatically...

Comment: Ah - maybe this was a bit unclear, sorry. The widths work fine, it's the heights that mess everything up. If the heights of the content on each widget varies, then the layout goes all crazy! I know I could set a standard height for the widgets using css, but thought this incrementation method might just be a bit 'cleaner' in the long run if it was possible.